# TextBox BackColor is hidden when TextBox.Enabled = false in Windows 11

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-11

In Windows 11 inside WinForms application. the Enabled = false for TextBox make it looks like its hidden.

[image: See Image]

and When Enabled = true. [image: See Enabled = true]

How to make BackColor same as Enabled=true.

I came from this topic: https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/750606-c-how-change-back-color-disabled-textbox-control

is there any way to get styles of Windows 7 inside TextBox or WinForms app generally.
I don't need to use Readonly property. I need to make same Color/style when Enabled = true, false.

Edit: I can change BackColor when override OnEnabledChanged event.
But this is not what I need. I need same style for Enabled = true/false for TextBox.

```
   public class Textbox2 : TextBox
   {
   protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
       if (Enabled)
           BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
       else
           BackColor = Color.White;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Toggle the `ReadOnly` property instead of the `Enabled`?